# Dynamic vs controllers with the same name

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

If I have a CMS and create a page called "Name" but I also have a controller called "Name"

Is there a way that I can make it so the page called "Name" does not override the controller

I have tried the following routes but it seems the CMS db page "Name" still overrides

**Routes:**

```
$route['name'] = "name";
$route['name/details/(:num)/(:num)'] = "screenings/details/$1/$2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the:

```
$route['name'] = "name";
```

after the:

```
$route['name/details/(:num)/(:num)'] = "screenings/details/$1/$2";
```

So in your case it will be:

```
$route['name/details/(:num)/(:num)'] = "screenings/details/$1/$2";
$route['name'] = "name/index"; //It is better to add the /index just to make sure
```

As far as I remember in Codeigniter the routes priority is what you add first.